# HTML Onclick Parameters according to C-Sharp

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

So I have the following code in HTML:

```
<% foreach (CommonLayer.GuidelineTagScript gts in current){ %>
                  <tr><td><% CommonLayer.Guideline thisg = new BusinessLogic.GuidelinesBL().GetGuideline(gts.GuidelineID);
                             if (gts.PassingScore < thisg.LevelOfImportance){%>

                      <img src="Images/Bad.png"/>
                       <%  } else {%>
                      <img src="Images/Good.png"/> <%} Response.Write(thisg.Name);  %>                  
                      <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="desc()"/>   <br />
                      <div id="<%Response.Write(thisg.GuideLineID);%>">
```

Take a look at the line before last, the input button. It has an onclick that links to the method desc, howevever I wish to pass a parameter with desc so that I can puss the thisg.GuidelineID (C-Sharp code). It obviously won't let me since I'm mixing JQuery with C-Sharp. Can you tell me about a way to work around this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your `onclick` needs to use `<%= %>` like:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" 
value="button" onclick='<%= "desc("+ thisg.GuideLineID +")" %>'/>
```

Actually you may want to replace this div too:

```
<div id="<%Response.Write(thisg.GuideLineID);%>">
```

with

```
<div id="<%=thisg.GuideLineID%>">
```